# A phone with a WiFi signal icon appears on the status bar (Samsung Galaxy S6, Android 5.1.1)

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-6, notification-icons

What does the following icon that looks like a phone with a WiFi signal in my status bar indicate? And how do I remove it?

[image]

As far as I know, I didn't turn any setting on that triggered it. I can't find the icon online. My first guess was that it was either VoLTE or VoIP or WiFi calling, but I do not have any of these as options on my phone.

The icon does not go away unless I turn off WiFi. Below are screenshots of my full home screen and of the open notification panel.

[image: Home screen] [image: Notification panel]

The screenshot below is of my phone's "Call Settings". I have no 'Wi-Fi Calling' option. According to guides online, it should come after the 'Vibrate' option. The screenshot below is the results when searching 'Wi-Fi' in settings. No call options come up.

[image] [image]

---

It definitely is the Wi-Fi Calling icon (even though I do not have it as an option on my phone) -- I tested it now and I can phone my contacts when in flight mode.

Comment: It looks very close to other WiFi Calling icons, so I'm pretty sure it's WiFi calling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, it indicates that for mobile calls, the WiFi will be used if there's a good WiFi signal.

I have found it [there](http://lowdown.carphonewarehouse.com/how-to/what-do-the-symbols-on-my-screen-mean/29341/):

> ## Small phone with Wi-Fi coming from it
>
> This strange new symbol shows your phone’s set up for Wi-Fi calling. It’s a new feature brought in by the UK’s biggest networks to help give you the best call quality. If your phone doesn’t have good reception, like when you’re indoors, it’ll make phone calls using an available Wi-Fi network instead.

Comment: Thanks :) You are correct. See EDIT 2 and 3 in OP. (I am still baffled how this setting is on though.)

Comment: What cell provider do you use? Sounds like they either enabled a feature they had turned off, or updated your phone to add support for wifi calling.

Comment: @remnant I think you could do something via the SIM menu - there should be such an app. Also try to open the phone app and check its settings.